# React Native refactorando class para function component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Novo no RN e estou tentando refatorar do class Component para function Component para usar hooks, mas na hora de setar o item da funcao .map(), aqui "setSentences(item);", nao esta reagindo, alguem sabe o que estou fazendo errado?

```
this.state = {
      sentences: [],
     };

{this.state.sentences.map((item) => {
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {
       item.selected = false;
       this.setState(item); 
      }}>
</TouchableOpacity>
)}}
```

**Refatorado:**

```
const [sentences, setSentences] = useState([]);

 {sentences.map((item) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          item.selected = false;
          setSentences(item);
        }}>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Se `sentences` é um array de itens, por que você está passando apenas um item para o `setSentences`?

Comment: porque cada vez que eu clicar no botao, esse item apenas quero que seja atualizado, do jeito que fiz assim: this.setState(item); , estava funcionando, mas talvez esteja algo errado aqui que nao sei o que e: setSentences(item);.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 {sentences.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          item.selected = false;
          sentences[index] = item
          setSentences(sentences);
        }}>
      </TouchableOpacity>
)})}
```

Comment: Obrigado Augusto